# AWS Cognito - resendConfirmationCode 'User is already confirmed.'

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-cognito

We have a scenario where a user forgets their username or password and can click on a *'Forgot password'* link, receiving a confirmation code in an SMS (via Cognito's [`ForgotPassword`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html)).

If, for some reason, the user doesn't receive the SMS, they can click on *'Resend code'* link which will execute Cognito's [`ResendConfirmationCode`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ResendConfirmationCode.html).

The result from the POST request is a 400 containing the following:
`{"__type":"InvalidParameterException","message":"User is already confirmed."}`

How can the user be confirmed when they have requested their confirmation code? Any clarification into the cause of this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but managed to get another SMS sent to Cognito user by simply resubmitting `ForgotPassword` instead of using `ResendConfirmationCode`.